# Toggle the css property of a div using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a code where I can toggle the CSS property of a div. Basically I'm trying to create a button that has a normal state and an active state.

Its normal color is blue but once you click it, it becomes green. Click it again and it goes back to being blue.

CSS:

```
    .lblue{
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
          0 -1px 1px #666, /*top external shadow*/ 
          inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/ 
          inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
        font-size: 16pt;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        color: white;
        background: #4bc2d3; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%, #70d6e2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4bc2d3), color-stop(100%,#70d6e2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4bc2d3', endColorstr='#70d6e2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        font-family: OpenSans-Semibold;
        float: left;
        }


        .lgreen{
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
              0 -1px 1px #666, /*top external shadow*/ 
              inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/ 
              inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
            font-size: 16pt;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            color: white;
            background: #7ebb44; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7ebb44 0%, #a5d063 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7ebb44), color-stop(100%,#a5d063)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #7ebb44 0%,#a5d063 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #7ebb44 0%,#a5d063 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #7ebb44 0%,#a5d063 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #7ebb44 0%,#a5d063 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7ebb44', endColorstr='#a5d063',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            font-family: OpenSans-Semibold;
            float: left;
            }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="lblue">Soul</div>
```

JS:

```
        $('.lblue').click(function() {
          $('.lblue').toggle(function() {
            $('.lblue').addClass('lgreen');

          });
        });
```

The problem with my code is that for some reason when I click the button, the button disappears as if it is sliding out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Toggle method shows/hides elements on each call.

```
$('.lblue').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('lgreen');
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this)` inside the callback, or else you may run into problems.

Comment: No problem. I took back my -1 :)

Comment: Notice this answer depends in the order which classnames `lblue` and `lgreen` were defined. If you invert the order, it will most likely stop working and all elements will be `lblue`. I addressed this in my own answer

Comment: (partly) Right answer, terrible explanation. Don't just throw a block of code at the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I can't agree with the rest of the answers. Even though they are correct they don't seem to be semantically correct, the classes of the elements will contain both `lblue` and `lgreen` classnames:

```
<div class="lblue lgreen">Soul</div>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^-- this is bad
```

And they will rely in the order which classnames were defined in your CSS.

Avoid future problems and use a semantically correct for what it is seen and what is is in the DOM:

```
$(document).on("click", ".lblue, .lgreen", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("lblue lgreen");
});​
```

If all your elements initial states are blue then:

```
$(".lblue").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("lblue lgreen");
});​
```

The former will work for dynamically added elements, the latter won't.

[Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ9Pw/)

Comment: @ Alexander "this by no means will generate a cyan colored element" there's a lot of ways to make this statement wrong, namely: defining the 'lgreen' class after the 'lblue' class in the css or using '!important'. If the css is well structured I think the 'toggle' solutions are much cleaner.

Comment: @nienn, not true. But, I agree. I will reduce my sarcasm and clean it up a bit

Comment: @ Alexander since you re-edited your post my comment doesn't make much sense anymore =). Your latter solution is cleaner. I still think you can keep the two classes thought, if you maintain a well structured CSS. This allows you to re-use  attributes from the lgreen class (thought, in this specific case, I agree with you in the fact that the classes containing the color names can make it counter intuitive).

Comment: @nienn, I'm also concerned about functionality though not only styles ;)

Comment: True, each has it's own advantages, I would pick the best fit for each specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You were using `.toggle()` incorrectly.

```
$('.lblue').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('lgreen');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain javascript you can use classList toggle
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

```
// div is an object reference to a <div> element with class="foo bar"
div.classList.remove("foo");
div.classList.add("anotherclass");
// if visible is set remove it, otherwise add it
div.classList.toggle("visible");
alert(div.classList.contains("foo"));
```

In your case: (assuming only one element to modify; see also querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName)

```
document.querySelector('.lblue').classList.toggle('lgreen');
```

Since it's quite new feature see: http://caniuse.com/classlist for browser compatibility

Comment: I appreciate the plain Javascript solution, but: why don't you use the classes the OP mentioned? Also, you should state something about browser support.

Comment: Edited to follow your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can check with the color and perform an event.

Eg.)

As in your case: 
Initial color = Blue.
Transformed color = Green

```
$('button handler').click(function () {
  if($(this).css('background-color') == 'BLUE') { 
    $(this).css('background-color', 'GREEN'); 
  } else { 
    $(this).css('background-color', 'BLUE'); 
  }
});
```

Just my guess. I don't really know for what exactly you are looking for.